# Posts not retrieving the created_at for comments

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to retrieve the created_at time for the comments, currently i can add a comment and it will show a time for it, but on refresh the time disappears.

time appears on submit

disappears on refresh, so it needs to be retrieved in the getPosts map method, but im unsure how to include that in.

Can someone point me the right direction, i know it has to do something with this

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections

This is what i currently have.

**PostController**

```
public function getPosts( )
{
    $posts = Post::with('user')
                 ->with(['likes' => function ($query) {
                            $query->whereNull('deleted_at');
                            $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);


                      }])
                  ->with(['comments' => function($query) {

                        $query->with('user');


                    }])

                    ->get();

    $data = $posts->map(function(Post $post, Comment $comment )
    { 
        $user = auth()->user();

        if($user->can('delete', $post)) {
            $post['deletable'] = true;
        }

        if($user->can('update', $post)) {
            $post['update'] = true;
        }



        $post['likedByMe'] = $post->likes->count() == 0 ? false : true;
        $post['likesCount'] = Like::where('post_id', $post->id)->get()->count();
        $post['createdAt'] = $post->created_at->diffForHumans();
        $post['createdAt'] = $post->updated_at->diffForHumans();
        // not getting the time for comments
        $comment['comment_createdAt'] = $comment->created_at->diffForHumans();

        return array($post, $comment);
    });



    return response()->json($data); 
}
```

**Comment Controller**

```
public function create(Request $request, $post)
{

    $data = request()->validate([
     'comment_body' => 'required|max:1000'
    ]);


    $data['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
    $data['name'] = auth()->user()->name;
    $data['post_id'] = $post;
    $post = Comment::create($data);
    // sets a time on a comment instantly im using angular :)
    $data['comment_createdAt'] = $post->created_at->diffForHumans();



    $response = new Response(json_encode($data));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 

    if(!$response){
        return 'something went wrong';
    }

    return response()->json($data); 


}
```

**html**

```
<div ng-show="comments" id="comments" class="col-md-offset-2  animated fadeIn panel-default" ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
    <div style="font-size:10px;" id="eli-style-heading" class="panel-heading">
      <a class="link_profile" href="/profile/<% comment.user.name | lowercase %>"><% comment.user.name %></a>
    </div>
    <figure class="my-comment">
        <p> <% comment.comment_body%>

        </p>

        <p><% comment.comment_createdAt %> </p>
          <hr>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: As I assume a post has many comments you can not just assign the created date of the post to **one** comment:

```
$post['comment_createdAt'] = $post->created_at->diffForHumans();
```

Instead you should have to loop over all comments and store the date in an array.

But this approach is a bit cumbersome because a Comment object already keeps the `created_at` value. I would just retrieve the date and format it in the frontend:

```
 <p><% comment.created_at | diffForHumans %> </p>
```

`diffForHumans` is a JS implementation which you have to write by yourself.

**Update**:

### Accessors

Model Comment:

```
class Comment  
{
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value) 
    { 
        return Carbon::createFromFormat($this->dateFormat, $value)
                       ->diffForHumans();
    }
}

<p><% comment.created_at %> </p>
```

But this will convert your `created_at` date all the time it get retrieved. A variation and better approach would be to use a custom Accessor:

```
class Comment  
{
    public function getCreatedAtHumanDiffedAttribute() 
    { 
        return Carbon::createFromFormat($this->dateFormat, $this->created_at)
                       ->diffForHumans();
    }
}

<p><% comment.created_at_human_diffed %> </p>
```

More about them [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators):

### API Resources

Use [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources). Your usecase is excactly what they are made for.

---

Honestly, your code has issues. Some remarks:

[image: PostController]

[image: CommentController]

Comment: the whole point of using `$post['comment_createdAt'] = $post->created_at->diffForHumans();` was just call it by `<% comment.comment_createdAt %>`

so i dont have to create a filter for diffForhumans.

Comment: I know there is some code that looks cumbersome  i know, but the main question was to retrieve the created at time. I appericaite the effort you put into writing your answer, but i just don't think my question has been solved. I like to pointers in the red, thanks.

Comment: I mentioned the solution on top of my answer: You need to iterate over the comments within `map()`, get the date and store it in an array.

Comment: and that is what i wanted to know, i needed to understand how to use map in code similar to what i have, this doesn't provide me any clear instructions on how to implement it with what i currently have.

Comment: this doesn't help https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-map im still left clueless

Comment: This has nothing todo with `map`.

Comment: i updated the post, let me know if im in the right direction, i get this error

`Type error: Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Comment, integer given`

i know you made an edit, but i want to learn it by the way i have it

Comment: oh yeah the Accessors didn't work, i get the default ugly timestamp

Comment: how are you calling `getCreatedDateAttribute()`